# Drupal 7 Ckeditor cannot edit profiles (picture added)

Tags: 7, wysiwyg

Recently I must have done something that changed something with my ckeditor.
I can no longer edit my profiles.
The strange thing is that I have multisite setup and only 3 sites are affected.
The 3 sites have a different theme, looked everywhere there but I cannot seem to find it.
Normally you see drop-down (clickable) buttons and then you can edit the options.
This is what I have now:

[image]

Anyone have an idea of what I might have done wrong?
The picture shows just plan text instead of buttons... I'm useing Omega 3.

Comment: Have you looked at console in Chrome or Firefox? My guess is JS error or resource not found to fully load the assets. Open firefox, go to Tools > Web Developer > Web Console and reload page.

Comment: does it happen for the admin on all sites, or could permissions to access html editting have changed?

Answer (score 1):

Broken unclickable fieldsets are almost always a symptom of JS not being run to build the links & click events to trigger expansion.

If the JS console is reporting errors, try to disable JS caching/aggregation, if possible, and look for offending JS errors that would stop execution. That should give you a good idea where it's coming from.

Most likely, the 3 affected sites have a similar configuration that is injecting JS which breaks further JS execution. Look for similar modules across the 3 sites. Good places to look are any custom modules, JQuery update (is it overriding the default jQuery from Drupal core?), custom blocks with JS, or any modules designed to inject ad-hoc JS snippets (I've come across sites using [JS snippets](https://www.drupal.org/project/js_snippets) despite its alpha status).

Comment: They indeed have a similar configuration. Though the only real difference is that they have a custom CSS. A different CSS for each of the 3. The other 5 websites have the same CSS and have no issues. All the websites, also the ones that are working fine have the same modules. They all share the ckeditor module so it's not like I messed up something in the ckeditor module files.
I'll search on, thanks for the thorough explanation!

Comment: If you're not seeing any JS errors, and you know the only significant difference is the theme & CSS files, you should look at class/id differences between the fieldsets on working sites vs non-working sites. If the theme is altering id/class attributes, it could be that selectors aren't catching the fieldset elements to enable links.

Comment: I found it, it was the Performance caching.. I checked some stuff there to make the website faster. I'll never forget this. What a stupid mistake! Thanks for the help!

Comment: Did you have aggressive caching on?

Comment: Yeah that was it :)